# Is there a standard way of audit tracking in grails?

Tags: grails, audit

Is there a grails plugin or standard way of managing the `created_by`, `created_on`, `updated_by`, `updated_on` fields for a domain object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you declare dateCreated and lastUpdated as Date they wil be maintained automatically by grails.
You can use the [Grails Audit Logging Plugin](http://www.grails.org/Grails+Audit+Logging+Plugin) to log the authenticated user under different security systems.

Comment: Small typo I guess: It's lastUpdated instead of lastUpdate. See http://www.grails.org/GORM+-+Events#Automatic%20timestamping

Comment: Thanks for spotting it! I just edited the answer to fix said typo.